# Bijection from conjugacy class to the factor group by centralizer.

Tags: group-theory

How different is $g^{-1}xg$ from $gxg^{-1}?$ Because proving a bijection from $g^{-1}xg$ type conjugacy class to the set of right cosets of the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ is as easy as proving it from  type $gxg^{-1}$ conjugacy class to the set of left cosets of the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. But I can't show such a bijection (specifically $1-1$) from $g^{-1}xg$ to left cosets or from $gxg^{-1}$ to right cosets using the method from Theorem 5.7 of http://goo.gl/qzH4IT.

Comment: It looks like you have mis-stated the theorem, which might explain why you cannot get the bijection you want. The correct theorem is that the conjugacy class of $x \in G$ corresponds bijectively to the set of left (or right) cosets of the centralizer of $x$ in $G$.  **Not** the centralizer of $g$ in $G$, which does not even make sense since this is a statement about $x$

Answer (score 1):

The two sets
$$A=\{ xgx^{-1} : x \in G\},  B=\{ x^{-1}gx : x \in G\}$$
are actually the same set.

In fact, for all $xgx^{-1} \in A$, denote $y= x^{-1}$, so you have
$$xgx^{-1} = y^{-1}gy \in B$$
Thus $A \subset B$. And you can prove similarly that $A \supset B$.

Comment: But please try to prove it the way I have asked and not by considering that they are the same.